# ASSIGNING PAGE NUMBER TO TABLE RECORDS ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling for a logic. 
Idea is I need to assign value 1 for first 10 records of the table, for next 10 records value should be 2, next 10 value should be 3 and so on.

I don`t want to go with loop concept, as the table is a large table, and nested loop to update the value will not be performance efficient. I might be wrong.

Please suggest, in Oracle SQL

Answer (score 1):

You need a column that specifies the ordering (SQL tables represent *unordered* sets).  After that, the solution is just `row_number()` with some arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (1 + trunc((row_number() over (order by orderingcol) - 1) / 10)) as grp
from t;
```

If you actually want to assign this to the table I would recommend using `merge`.  However, calculating the value in a query may be sufficient for your purposes.